# BASH: let construct (( ... ))

Tags: bash

Can anyone explain the following?

```
1. (( 0 && 1 ))                 # Logical AND
echo $?     # 1     ***
# And so ...
2. let "num = (( 0 && 1 ))"
echo $num   # 0
# But ...
3. let "num = (( 0 && 1 ))"
echo $?     # 1     ***
```

If 1 is the exit code of 1., then shouldn't num in 2. contain the same exit code?

Comment: it's echo $num actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`num` isn't assigned the exit code of the arithmetic command. It is assigned the value of `0 && 1`; here, the double parentheses are simply treated as nested subexpressions. The `let` statement is equivalent to

```
(( num = (( 0 && 1 )) ))
```

with the RHS of the `=` operator treated as an expression, not a statement.

Comment: So, `(( num = (( 0 && 1 )) ))` is the same as `(( num = 0 && 1 ))`, 0.

Answer (score 2):

**Reason:** Exit status is different from the command's output.

- **Example 1:** You're looking at command's exist status.
- **Example 2:** You're looking at the command's output.